# Javascript Syntax error in web app through vagrant (altered source code)

Tags: javascript, vagrant

For some reasons I keep getting a syntax error in my js file after I have edited it.
When I click on the source the code is different and the error is even on a place I did not edit.

I worked on line 50-54 and the error is suddenly occurring on line 131
Also the code I placed at 50-54 is not even in the source of the web app.

My code at the end:

```
function exportTravelTimeHistory()
{
    var trajectory = $('#trajectory').val();
    var date = $('#dateFrom').val();

    window.location = '/traveltime/index/history-data/format/csv/dateFrom/' + date +     '/trajectory/' + trajectory;
}
```

What I get in source at the end:

```
function exportTravelTimeHistory()
{
    var trajectory = $('#trajectory').val();
    var date = $('#dateFrom').val();

    window.location = '/traveltime/index/history-data/format/csv/dateFrom/' + date +     '/trajectory/' + trajectory;
}
???????????ortTravelTimeHistory()
{
    var trajectory = $('#trajectory').val();
    var date = $('#dateFrom').val();

    window.location = '/traveltime/index/history-data/format/csv/dateFrom/' + date + '/trajectory/' + traject
```

I work on my host (OSX) but it is a shared folder with vagrant machine.

I checked for hidden characters and such.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know the exact reason why this happens, updating guest additions, using NFS, and restarting did the trick for me.

#### 1. Update the VirtualBox and its Guest Additions

- Update your VirtualBox installation if necessary.
- Boot your virtual machine from the Virtual Box interface.
- Click the **Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD Image...** menu item.
- In the virtual machine, run the following:

```
    $ sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
    ## Or sudo mount /dev/cdrom1 /media/cdrom
    ## if you got the error "mount: no medium found on /dev/sr1:".
    $ sudo apt-get install -y dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r)
    $ sudo /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

#### 2. Use NFS shared folders

In your Vagrantfile set `type: "nfs"`.

Example from the [Vagrant docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html):

`config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"`

#### 3. Reload your virtual machine with `vagrant reload`.

Comment: Thank you, seems to have fixed the issue